# Iterator assignment issue Java

Tags: java

So my assignment requires that I implement an interface in one of my class. The interface is a generic Iterator, which I will have to override the hasNext() and next() methods. I'm getting an error when I try to assign the instance ArrayList iterator to the instance Iterator.

Here's my interface:

```
public interface Iterator <E>
{
    boolean hasNext();
    E next();
    void remove();
}// end Iterator interface
```

And here's the class that implements that interface:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WordDatabase implements Iterator<String>
{
// Declaration
private List<String> aList;
private Iterator<String> aListIterator;

    /**** Other Class Methods Here *****/

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void shuffle()
{
    // Declaration
    int rand;
    String temp;

    // Statement
    // shuffling ArrayList
    for(int i = 0; i < getAlist(); i++)
    {
        rand = (int)(Math.random() * getAlist() - 1);

        // swapping two ArrayList entry

        temp = aList.get(i);
        aList.remove(i);
        aList.add(i, aList.get(rand));
        aList.remove(rand);
        aList.add(rand, temp);
    }

    aListIterator = aList.iterator();

    return;
}// end shuffle method
```

Eclipse is telling me that I need to cast `aList.iterator()` to `Iterator<String>`, but doing so throws an error `java.util.AbstractList$Itr cannot be cast to Iterator`. Can someone help me figure this problem out?

Comment: When you say "Here's my interface" do you mean here is a sample of the java.util.Interator?  Or do you have your own declaration of the Iterator interface in your own package?  If you have your own Iterator interface, that would cause problems.

Comment: @AgilePro Yes, I have my own iterator interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that as both `Iterator` objects belong to different packages.

You have to define your own `List` interface as you did for `Iterator`; Define a method `iterator()` which returns object of your interface `Iterator`.

Comment: Hm, I see. Maybe I might have misinterpreted the assignment. Because my teacher would have told us we would need a separate interface for List. I'm going to email my professor now for clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What i understood from the exception is You have defined your own **Interface** as **Iterator** so now there would not be any relation with List.
So you can't Cast.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.util.List.iterator` method returns an instance of `java.util.Iterator`, and not your `my.special.Iterator` interface.  But you have declared the variable as `my.special.Iterator` interface.  Though they have the same simple name, they are actually different types, and Eclipse wants you to cast it, which you can't because they are not related.

You would have to implement your own special List class as well, or avoid using the `iterator` method.

Comment: Yeah, couple other people have said the same thing. I just emailed my professor about this. Maybe I misinterpreted what she meant, because she actually showed us the interface and said use this actually interface. Which is the one I posted above.

Comment: The Interface you listed is identical to `java.util.Iterator`, so it is possible that you can just use `java.util.Iterator` to complete the assignment, and throw your copy away to solve the problem.  If this answer was helpful, check it as an accepted answer (little check mark on the left.)

Answer (score 0):

the `Iterator<String> aListIterator` is your iterator interface and the iterator returned by `aList.iterator();` is java.util.Iterator.

The names are same but packages different (i am presuming that). So you cant cast them. But to actually iterate a list using your iterator you need to extend the list and implement your iterator inside it. which is what your `WordDatabase` class is trying to do. try to use an array in your class instead of a list.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I actually can't use arrays.

Comment: you havent shown the implementation your own iterator interface methods her. Can you add those too?

Comment: I was just going to override the methods listed above to the requirement on the homework assignment. I didn't get a chance to override them yet, because of the error I was receiving. Sorry.